Optimal approach to set model value to a Combo box in Edit case in Angular
Context
This question is more related to logic rather than resolving an error.
I have a combo box (here, I am using Kendo UI) that uses listItems as the data source and selectedValues as the model.
The typescript code does an API call to fetch the data source. Same component is used for Add as well as Edit case
HTML code
<kendo-combobox
    [data]="listItems"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedValues">
</kendo-combobox>

TS code
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public listItems: Array<Product> = [];
  public selectedValues: any;
  id: number = 0;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.loadComboData(); //load combo box data source

    if(this.id != undefined && this.id > 0) { // call only in Edit case
        this.loadFormDataForEdit(); // load saved form data
    }
  }
  
  loadComboData() {
       this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe((data) => {
          this.listItems = data;
       });
  }

  loadFormDataForEdit() {
      this.dataService.fetchFormData(this.id).subscribe((data) => {
          this.selectedValues = data;
       });
  }
}

Change done to accommodate edit case
This is a form that is used for Adding/Editing data. In case of edit, I will need to bind the combo box data source first and then set the model, so that the user can change the combo box value and save it.
Here, I can't be certain that loadComboData() API call will return the value before loadFormDataForEdit(). Therefore, model won't be bound.
So, I had to modify the code as below.
FYI, id will be greater than 0 in Edit case
  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.loadComboData();
  }

  loadComboData() {
       this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe((data) => {
          this.listItems = data;
          
          if(this.id != undefined && this.id > 0) { // calling inside subscribe of combo box
              this.loadFormDataForEdit();
          }
       });
  }

  loadFormDataForEdit() {
      this.dataService.fetchFormData(this.id).subscribe((data) => {
          this.selectedValues = data;
       });
  }

Question
Now the above approach works fine for simple cases. But what in case of the below points?

If the form is large and has multiple combo boxes?

Here, it would be difficult to know in which combo box load function should I put loadFormDataForEdit()



Please refer the inline comments.
...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.loadComboData1();
    this.loadComboData2();
  }

  loadComboData1() {
       this.dataService.fetchData1().subscribe((data) => {
          this.listItems1 = data;
          // should call this.loadFormDataForEdit() here? 
       });
  }
  loadComboData2() {
       this.dataService.fetchData2().subscribe((data) => {
          this.listItems2 = data;
          // OR should call this.loadFormDataForEdit() here? 
          // but order of execution will still be a concern
       });
  }
...



Cascaded combo boxes makes it more complex.

I need guidance to understand the correct approach.
